# SP - CodError with CAML query,

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, caml-query, caml

I want go **get last record field value from my SPList with CAML query**. Really code **working** but gives me following ERROR...

**My Code:**

```
void ddCarNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

       SPWeb myWEB = SPContext.Current.Web;

        SPList myList = myWEB.Lists["WayBill"];

        SPQuery myQuery = new SPQuery();
        myQuery.Query = @"<OrderBy>
                            <FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='FALSE' /> 
                        </OrderBy> 
                        <Where>
                            <Eq>
                                <FieldRef Name='CarNumber1'/>
                                <Value Type='Text'>" + ddCarNumber.Text + @"</Value>
                            </Eq>
                        </Where>";

           SPListItemCollection myItemCol = myList.GetItems(myQuery);

            if (myItemCol.Count > 0)
            {
                string myEndMil = myItemCol[0]["endMil"].ToString();

                string digitsOnly = String.Empty;
                foreach (char c in myEndMil)
                {
                    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                    {
                        digitsOnly += c;
                    }
                }

                txtStartMil.Text = digitsOnly;
            }
            else
            {
                txtStartMil.Text = string.Empty;
            }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {   
       lblError.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Error is :**

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the
>   range of valid values. at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.get_Item(Int32 iIndex) at
>   Lirex.WayBillModule.ddCarNumber_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below method:

```
void ddCarNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

       SPWeb myWEB = SPContext.Current.Web;

        SPList myList = myWEB.Lists["WayBill"];

        SPQuery myQuery = new SPQuery();
        myQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='CarNumber1'/><Value Type='Text'>" + ddCarNumber.Text + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

           SPListItemCollection myItemCol = myList.GetItems(myQuery);

            if (myItemCol.Count > 0)
            {
                if(myItemCol[0]["endMil"] != null)
                {
                    string myEndMil = myItemCol[0]["endMil"].ToString();

                    string digitsOnly = String.Empty;
                    foreach (char c in myEndMil)
                    {
                        if (Char.IsDigit(c))
                        {
                            digitsOnly += c;
                        }
                    }
                }
                txtStartMil.Text = digitsOnly;
            }
            else
            {
                txtStartMil.Text = string.Empty;
            }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {   
       lblError.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 3):

Here `string myEndMil = myItemCol[0]["endMil"].ToString();` you are assuming you have gotten at least one result back. That might not be the case!

You should check first that `myItemCol.Count > 0`

There is another possible issue at the same line (`string myEndMil = myItemCol[0]["endMil"].ToString();`)

You are requesting a column `endMil` that you might not have.

Comment: see my code, maybe this ??

Answer (score 2):

Can you try putting `<RowLimit>1</RowLimit>` in the Query. The row limit will return only the one last item.

Comment: paste this in my query, please :)

Comment: put   myQuery.RowLimit = 1; before SPListItemcollection line

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Added some safe checks

```
void ddCarNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {    
        SPWeb myWEB = SPContext.Current.Web;

        SPList myList = myWEB.Lists.TryGetList("WayBill");
        if(myList != null)
        {
           SPQuery myQuery = new SPQuery();
           myQuery.Query = @"<OrderBy>
                            <FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='FALSE' /> 
                        </OrderBy> 
                        <Where>
                            <Eq>
                                <FieldRef Name='CarNumber1'/>
                                <Value Type='Text'>" + ddCarNumber.Text + @"</Value>
                            </Eq>
                        </Where>";

            myQuery.RowLimit = 1; 
            SPListItemCollection myItemCol = myList.GetItems(myQuery);

            if (myItemCol != null && myItemCol.Count > 0)
            {
                string digitsOnly = String.Empty;
                string myEndMil = String.Empty;
                if(myItemCol[0]["endMil"] != null)
                {
                   myEndMil = Convert.ToString(myItemCol[0]["endMil"]);    

                   foreach (char c in myEndMil)
                   {
                       if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                       {
                           digitsOnly += c;
                       }
                   }
                }
                txtStartMil.Text = digitsOnly;
            }
            else
            {
                txtStartMil.Text = String.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {   
       lblError.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

- While fetching a list use TryGetList like this `myWEB.Lists.TryGetList("WayBill");`
- Use ID Column possibly when performing a ORDER BY operation. Since ID is indexed column, query execute faster.
- You must always do a null check when query is fired and data is assigned to `SPListItemCollection`
- You should try to keep practice of using `Convert.ToString()` instead of `.ToString()` for ex `Convert.ToString(myItemCol[0]["endMil"]);` and not `myItemCol[0]["endMil"].ToString()`
- Also check if column exists or not. `if(myItemCol[0]["endMil"] != null)`